# How to achieve the current bing map NavigationBarMode on Bing V8?

Tags: bing-maps, bing

We are currently using bing maps V8 and am trying to achieve the current bing maps navigation bar mode which looks something like this [bing maps navigation bar mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAoPz.png) on https://www.bing.com/maps.

These are the properties that I have added to my code

```
navigationBarMode: navigationBarMode.compact,
navigationBarOrientation: Microsoft.Maps.NavigationBarOrientation.vertical,
showLocateMeButton: true
```

The first line helped me to get the Map Type drop down and second line is to align the zoom in and out vertically because by default compact mode is setting up the zoom in and out button horizontally and the third line displays the locate me icon.

The problem with this approach is the Birds Eye view is not working as expected once I click the Bird's Eye view the "X" on the top right corner doesn't show up.

Is there any alternate way to achieve the current bing maps navigation bar mode?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be fixed in the experimental branch of Bing Maps V8. Try adding &branch=experimental to the map script URL in your app and see if the issue is resolved. All fixes in the experimental branch will be pushed into the main release branch near the end of this month.